# Getting extra symbols and numbers after reading csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, character-encoding

I have a csv file containing text, where after reading it in R, I am getting some unwanted symbols and numbers.
How to remove all these unwanted ones from the file?

Example:
My csv file has two text columns= Question and Answer

Original Question (before opening in R):

> Where do I see my bank's account details?

Original Answer:

> That's a frequently asked question. You can find details at this link.

After reading the file, I am getting like:

Question:

> Where do I see my bankâ€™s account details?

Answer:

> That39;s a frequently asked question. You can find details at this link.

I tried saving in UTF-8 and then read the file,

```
df <-read.csv("data.csv", encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But still some unwanted symbols and numbers are appearing as shown above. How do I remove them?

Comment: This looks like some sort of encoding problem.  What do you see in the original file when you open it in something Notepad or a similar text editor?

Comment: I am using Excel to view original file.

Comment: For reference: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `read_excel()` from the `readxl` package

```
library(readxl)
df = read_excel("data.csv")
```

Comment: I tried but getting error "Error: Can't establish that the input is either xls or xlsx."

Comment: If I convert into xlsx and then use read_excel, it worked without symbols. But if I want to use csv file, how can i go about it as I still get extra symbols.

Comment: Problem is even my RDS file upon uploading csv file, is having numbers like 39; or 24; in place of apostrophe in text. So how to get apostrophe and not numbers.